# Gettin values outside functions of nouisliders

Tags: javascript, function, nouislider

I am having a trouble with getting values of two noUiSliders outside of functions.

Here is the jsbin file: 
http://jsbin.com/havabemugi/edit?css,js,console,output

I can do a console.log of two values in both functions, but when I am trying to access them outside the error occures.

I need to store them in two different variables and have an access to them globally.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a global variable and assign a value to it in your function.  You can then reference that global variable anywhere.  I created a new Bin where I save the value of slider 1 to a global variable, then output that value when slider2 is moved:  http://jsbin.com/guvogocusi/1/edit?js,console,output

And here's the code:

```
var rangeSlider1 = document.getElementById('rangeslider1');
var rangeSlider2 = document.getElementById('rangeslider2');
var slider1Val;

noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider1, {
  start: 5,
  step: 1,
  connect: 'lower',
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 80
  }
});

noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider2, {
  start: 5,
  step: 1,
  connect: 'lower',
  range: {
    min: 0,
    max: 80
  }
});

function getValue1(values, handle, unencoded, tap) {
  console.log("value of slider1: " + unencoded);
  slider1Val = unencoded;
}

function getValue2(values, handle, unencoded, tap) {
  console.log(slider1Val);  
}

rangeSlider1.noUiSlider.on('update', getValue1);
rangeSlider2.noUiSlider.on('update', getValue2);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works but I need slider1Val variable outside of getValue2 function as well and I want slider1Val updated every time first sliders value changes

Comment: $('#rangeslider1').on('click', function() { 
  console.log(slider1Val);
}

helped :)